# Should I delete an old off-topic closed post that pre-dates other stackexchange sites?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, old-questions

I posted [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121/why-are-system-and-taskmgr-exe-taking-up-100-of-my-cpu) long ago during the first few weeks of the Stack Overflow private beta. It was closed (rightfully) a few years ago for being off-topic.  The consensus of what was on-topic and off-topic hadn't been decided at the time I wrote the question, though now it certainly is not an appropriate Stack Overflow question. Occasional downvotes for it (including today, presumably because it's now so off-topic) remind me about the question and make me think about whether I should just delete it. The accepted answer did provide some help to me at the time, however, so that makes me think that there might be some value in letting it remain. I guess I assumed that moderators would delete or migrate it if it were too egregious.

Should I delete it?

Comment: You can't, as there's an upvoted answer.

Comment: Oh, good point.

Comment: But we can delete it, just voted.

Comment: It's gone now.Live long and prosper!

Comment: The [on hold] reason here should be read like [meta-tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 2):

You couldn't delete it even if you wanted to.  It has multiple answers.